# ¿Es correcta una relación circular en Mysql?

Tags: mysql

Buen día a todos, esta es mi primera pregunta por acá y de antemano agradezco su apoyo y espero también poder colaborar.

En una base de datos tengo tres tablas:

- Usuario (persona que registra la operación)
- Venta
- AbonoVenta (pagos de las ventas que son al crédito)

Mis relaciones las tengo así:

- Usuario -> Venta (Uno a muchos)
- Venta -> AbonoVenta (Uno a muchos)

La tabla AbonoVenta la utilizo para registrar los pagos de las ventas que son al crédito.

Quiero hacer una relación entre Usuario y AbonoVenta para poder registrar qué usuario operó el abono. Al hacerlo tendría un círculo. Mi duda es si es correcto un diseño de esa forma o si habría algún inconveniente en la base de datos o si es una mala práctica en el modelo relacional. Muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: edita y recta mejor tu pregunta todo continuo es dificil de leer

Comment: Está bien, lo haré.

Comment: Son dos escenarios diferentes, unos son las ventas de contado y otro las ventas a crédito, es decir, se debe tener en cuenta los procesos del negocio al momento de diseñar.
Si separa esos dos escenarios la relación del usuario es con la Venta_Credito, y los Abonos la relación directa sería con la Venta_Credito, en la tabla Abono, lo importante es saber la fecha del abono y el monto, ya que se supone que quién abona es el usuario que hizo la compra a crédito (esto se sabría solo haciendo una consulta con Inner Join). Si le interesa saber quién fue la persona que hizo deposito, puede agregar un

Answer (score 2):

Realmente no comprendo el concepto de AbonoVenta, pero para la relación que le has puesto con Ventas debe de cumplir que una venta pueda tener varios abonos.

Si esto fuera así, tienes esta relación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

O leído en voz alta, un usuario tiene entre cero y n ventas, y una venta tiene entre 0 y n abonos.

Poner el usuario en los abonos es redundante, ya que si quisieras, por ejemplo, todos los usuarios de todos tus abonos, podrías sacarlo con:

```
SELECT * FROM USUARIO JOIN VENTAS ON USUARIO.ID_USER = VENTAS.FK_USUARIO JOIN ABONOS ON VENTAS.ID_VENTAS = ABONOS.FK_VENTA
```

Esto te devolvería exclusivamente los usuarios que tienen ventas que contienen abonos, si hay varios abonos para una venta te devolvería duplicados, pero nada que no solvente un **DISTINCT** ;)

En resumen ¿Está mal tu diseño? Mal es una palabra muy fuerte, pero estoy convencido de que vulnera alguna [Forma normal](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forma_normal_(base_de_datos)). Simplemente vas a tener reduncancia y los errores que eso pueda conllevar.

Comment: Te agradezco mucho tu respuesta y si, es así como me lo has planteado en la imagen. 

Abono son los pagos; por ejemplo Venta registra un PC que un usuario vendió, pero si fue al crédito y se va pagar en 3 pagos por ejemplo, AbonoVenta registra cada uno de esos pagos. 

Mi duda está en que si puedo crear una llave foránea Fk_Usuario por ejemplo en la tabla Abonos.

Comment: Algo que olvidé mencionar es que el usuario que registra el Abono puede ser diferente al que operó la venta. Es por eso que veo la necesidad de la llave foránea Fk_Usuario en la tabla Abono.

Comment: Sí, ese detalle es quizás importante, más que nada si un usuario que hace una venta no es el que hace la transacción. Ahí no veo más remedio que poner una relación circular, lo importante es, sin embargo, que la relación es distinta. Y como he dicho antes, la reduncancia es lo único incorrecto que puedes llevar contigo, pero es  algo ínfimo. A menos que alguien tenga una idea mejor, diría que es lo más eficiente.

Comment: Veré cómo funciona entonces y tienes razón sobre el tema de la redundancia. Subí una imagen y es que no sabía que se podía hasta ver tu respuesta.

Comment: Disculpa, después de estar pensando sobre esto, se me ocurrió una cosa ¿Ventas tiene al usuario como vendedor y Abonos como comprador, no es así? En ese caso, a menos que para varios abonos de una misma venta pueda haber varias personas distintas que abonan, podrías mantener el estilo lineal teniendo una clave foránea para comprador y otra para vendedor en "Ventas".

Comment: No realmente, Usuario es la persona que registra en la computadora las Ventas y también los Abonos (pagos por las ventas). Usuario es el operador de la aplicación.