# Como evito el cierre en este modelo logico en sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, modelorelacional, diagrama-er

Como evito el cierre de este modelo logico, segun me explicaron las entidades no deben generar un cierre, en este caso el modelo intenta cumplir lo siguiente: Se desea guardar informacion acerca de las recetas para hacer una torta, el cual es un producto, asi como sus ingredientes. En la tabla producto se guardaria los pasteles y los ingredientes, en la tabla receta se guarda el ID de la torta(ID_producto) y en receta_ingredientes se guarda los id de los productos asociados con cada ID de receta, sin embargo, estas relaciones generan un cierre o un bucle, lo cual estaria mal, como lo puedo evitar??????
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Tu modelo tiene varios problemas.

1)No estas aplicando las reglas de normalización. Te aconsejo leerlas [aqui](https://bookdown.org/paranedagarcia/database/normalizacion.html).

2)Tus tablas están mal diseñadas, ese modelo estoy seguro que no satisface nada.

3)Debes saber identificar que tipo de relación se requiere entre cada tabla de tu modelo. Te recomiendo leer sobre relaciones y cardinalidad [aqui](https://bookdown.org/paranedagarcia/database/modelamiento-de-datos.html#relaci%C3%B3nes).

El modelo que buscas según tu planteamiento es algo así:

[image: Modelo producto-receta]

Y en lenguaje SQL seria lo siguiente:

```sql
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`unidad_medida`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`unidad_medida` (
  `id_unidad_medida` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `descripcion` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `abreviatura` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `activo` TINYINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_unidad_medida`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`categoria`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`categoria` (
  `id_categoria` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `descripcion` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `activo` TINYINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_categoria`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`producto_final`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`producto_final` (
  `id_producto` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  `descripcion` VARCHAR(250) NULL,
  `id_unidad_medida` INT NOT NULL,
  `id_categoria` INT NOT NULL,
  `fecha_ingreso` DATE NOT NULL,
  `SKU` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_producto`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_producto_UNIQUE` (`id_producto` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_producto_final_unidad_medida1_idx` (`id_unidad_medida` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_producto_final_categoria1_idx` (`id_categoria` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_producto_final_unidad_medida1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_unidad_medida`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`unidad_medida` (`id_unidad_medida`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_producto_final_categoria1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_categoria`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`categoria` (`id_categoria`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`receta`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`receta` (
  `id_receta` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_producto_final` INT NOT NULL,
  `descripcion` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_receta`),
  INDEX `fk_receta_producto_final_idx` (`id_producto_final` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_receta_producto_final`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_producto_final`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`producto_final` (`id_producto`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`ingrediente`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`ingrediente` (
  `id_ingrediente` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `descripcion` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  `id_receta` INT NOT NULL,
  `id_unidad_medida` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_ingrediente`),
  INDEX `fk_ingrediente_receta1_idx` (`id_receta` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_ingrediente_unidad_medida1_idx` (`id_unidad_medida` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_ingrediente_receta1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_receta`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`receta` (`id_receta`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_ingrediente_unidad_medida1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_unidad_medida`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`unidad_medida` (`id_unidad_medida`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Hola sisi, es que recorte de un diagrama que ya tenia en borrador, mi pregunta solo era acerca de los cierres o "relaciones circulares" que en tu diagrama se siguen presentando, en la univerisidad siempre nos aconsejaban no hacerlas, entonces un diagrama con esta relacion circular si es posible implementarla a un diseño real????

Comment: Otra cosa, en tu diagrama la tabla Receta e Ingrediente deberia tener una tabla intermedia para que guarde la clave foranea de la receta y del ingrediente, asi poder  tener un registro de que ingredientes tiene cada receta

Comment: Bueno, seria circular si por ejemplo, en categoría o unidad de medida tuviera el id_producto, lo cual no ocurre aquí. En cuanto a la tabla intermedia que comentas 1 producto solo se puede crear siguiendo una única receta. Por ejemplo, tu producto puede ser un CheeseCake clasico, el cual tiene su receta, pero si creas un CheeseCake de chocolate, usarías la misma receta? Por eso se establece una relación 1 a 1. Por otro lado para el CheeseCake usas queso, el cual puede estar en la receta clásica y en la de chocolate, de ahí, un ingrediente puede estar en muchas recetas =relación 1 a muchos o 1-n

Comment: [Aca](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/150031/es-correcta-una-relaci%C3%B3n-circular-en-mysql) hay una pregunta similar a la tuya donde quizás puedas aclarar algunas dudas también.