# Relacion circular en diseño de modelo logico sql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, base-de-datos, modelorelacional, diagrama-er

tengo este problema en mi modelo logico en el cual se esta generando una relacion circular entre las entidades, como puedo solucionar este diseño o como podria replantearlo, no se me ocurre mucho. Se trata de lo siguiente: Se desea guardar los productos finales que produce la empresa como Tortas, un producto puede tener muchas recetas y cada receta tiene sus ingredientes, ademas se le da una unidad de medida al producto y al ingrediente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y cual es el problema que sea circular?

Comment: segun se, habria problemas al hacer eliminaciones o actualizaciones de registros y es una mala practica hacerlas, he leido que no estan recomendadas y que si hay una relacion circular es porque el diseño esta mal hecho

Comment: Mira no soy experto en base de datos, pero yo no veo nada malo en tu modelo. Nunca había escuchado que es una mala práctica, es que si lo fuera se hablaría que el modelo debe ser un árbol y no un grafo como lo es, incluso yo creo que es muy común que salga el modelo circular cuando creas un una especie de "tipo" como es tu tabla `UMedida`, hay otros caso típicos como crear una tabla `Ciudad` que luego se relaciona con `Cliente`, `Vendedor` y `Sucursal`.

Comment: Sobre estas relaciones circulares en la universidad siempre nos decían que debíamos evitarlas porque eran un problema del diseño, intente preguntar a IA pero no me dan resultado correctos, aquí hay algo de info donde se recomienda no tener relaciones circulares, esta en los últimos párrafos https://programacion.net/articulo/modelo_relacional_172/3

Comment: Por otro lado, me parece que a `Producto_final` y a `Ingrediente` le faltan los FK de `UMedida`

Comment: Si, olvide de añadirlos, lo editare

Comment: Yo estaba viendo el modelo entero, que exista una línea que pase por todas las tablas no hay problema. Donde parece ser que tienes un problema de referencia circular son con las tablas `Producto_final` y `Receta`

Comment: En realidad no hay una relacion circular, porque la tabla UMedida es una tabla que solo se usa para normalizar un campo... las relaciones que te explicaron a vos (y se ve que muy mal) son sobre tablas que tengan datos principales... si eliminaras la tabla UMedida, no "pasaria" nada, es mas esa tabla casi que podria estar "harcodeada" y no "pasaria" nada (todo en potencial, porque no es correcto, pero se podria)

Comment: @gbianchi fíjate en las tablas `Producto_final` y `Recetas` (solo en esas 2), ahí me parece que tiene un problema circular (siempre y cuando los FK sean not null), ya que no podría crear un producto sin que la receta existe, pero tampoco puede crear la receta sin que el producto exista

Comment: @Yussef tienes razón, tengo que sacarle la FK de receta a la tabla productos, eso me pasa por subirlo sin revisar

Comment: @gbianchi por que consideras que no existe una relación circular? si se esta generando un cierre en los diagramas

Comment: @Yussef no veo lo que me decis... si la relacion es 1 a muchos porque no podria?

Comment: @Jocar me dices donde ves la relacion circular??? la tabla UMedida no cuenta en las relaciones...

Comment: @gbianchi jajaja justamente en la tabla UMedida, se esta relacionando con las tablas de Producto e Ingrediente y se cierran, un ejemplo similar lo vi en este foro y no se dio solucion
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/150031/es-correcta-una-relaci%C3%B3n-circular-en-mysql

Comment: no entendiste mi explicacion anterior no?? la leiste???

Comment: @gbianchi si la lei, pero no la entiendo, porque dices que borrar la tabla UMedida no "afectaria" nada, si se borra, los registros de Producto y de ingredientes solo contarian con su cantidad pero no se sabria si son kilos, litros, etc

Comment: Aparte de lo que comenta gbianchi. La pregunta que enlazas sí fue respondida. Otra cosa es que el OP, el que preguntaba, la marcara como aceptada. La respuesta plantea que las relaciones no eran circulares.

Comment: Quisiera saber el porqué esa tabla no es tan importante como las demás, que pasaría si se borra, los demás registros quedan sin saber que unidad de medida es, quisiera saber el porqué de esto, si me pueden ayudar porque no lo entiendo

Comment: Voy a tratar de ser más claro: Que el modelo sea circular, es decir que visualmente exista una línea que una varias entidades y que visualmente forme un camino circular no tiene ningún problema. Caso distinto son las referencias circulares, que es lo que te pasaba antes con `Producto_final` y `Recetas`. Tu tabla `UMedida` es la que produce que el MODELO sea circular, pero esa tabla no tiene referencias (FK) de otras tablas, por lo que no tienes REFERENCIAS circulares

Comment: Por ejemplo, para crear un `Producto_final` necesitas que exista `UMedida`, para crear `Receta` necesitas que exista `Producto_final`, para crear `Receta_ingrediente` necesitas que exista `Receta` y `Ingrediente`, para crear `Ingrediente` necesitas  `UMedida`, pero para crear `UMedida` no necesitas otra tabla, ahí se rompe lo circular. O visto de un modo visual (no sé si será valido para todos los casos, pero lo es para el tuyo) cambia esas 3 rayas de la relación *1 a muchos* por una punta de flecha, y sigue el camino, no podrás dar una vuelta

Comment: Es mucho mas simple, tu tabla UMedida no es una tabla principal, es una tabla auxiliar, que en este caso es compartida por varias otras tablas. Pero es una tabla que no sufriria cambios diarios, ni semanales, bah, capaz no la cambias por años, porque las medidas de las cosas no cambian... es una tabla que tranquilamente podria estar hardcodeada.. y es una tabla que podrias evitar en todas las relaciones, porque solo tiene las descripciones de las medidas... se entiende ahora porque no es una tabla importante????

Comment: Es mas, capaz que ni le haces un ABM en tu sistema, porque es una tabla que casi no cambia y no es necesario... ahora, te das cuenta que si sacas esa tabla, y hardcodeas lo que esta ahi, todo el modelo funciona igual????

Comment: El modelo no creo esté mal, solo hay que seguir una secuencia lógica y cumplir con determinadas reglas para evitar "constraints violations", ya sea desde un store procedure o desde la aplicación en sí.

Answer (score 0):

No veo una relación circular, pero sí vas a tener problemas al eliminar algunos registros de UMedida o de Receta o de ingredientes.  Te recomiendo que pongas campos de estado, para dejar de usarlos, pero que existan mientras existan los registros que los usan.
Ojo.  Se supone que un producto final debiera tener una única receta.

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]